# How to represent set of java objects as a field of other object in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, jpa

I have a class Exercise and Training. I would like to have a set of exercises within each training. My question is - how to represent that in database and in java?

What I thought about was to add an exercise to a specific training basing on `training_id` which is foreign key in `exercise` table.
But I want to store every exercise within one training in one set or just list that is a field of Training class - I think that is the good way of doing it, but I might be wrong.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercise")
public class Exercise {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "exercise_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "exercise_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    private double weight;

    @Column(name = "series")
    private int series;

    @Column(name = "training_id")
    private int trainingId;
```

```java
@Table(name = "training")
public class Training {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "training_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "training_name")
    private String trainingName;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    private Set<Exercise> exercises;
```

Maybe I don't understand the concept of it. Could anybody show me a proper way of doing it?

Comment: You tagged your question with `jdbc`. But your code shows JPA entities. So, are you using JDBC, or JPA?

Comment: my fault, sorry - JPA of course

Comment: Then you need to learn it. It's a complex beast. Read a good book about it, and/or the Hibernate documentation. It has a complete section on associations between entities, which are an essential, fundamental building block of JPA. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
@Table(name = "training")
public class Training {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "training_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "training_name")
    private String trainingName;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "training")
    private Set<Exercise> exercises = new HashSet<>();


@Entity
@Table(name = "exercise")
public class Exercise {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "exercise_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "exercise_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    private double weight;

    @Column(name = "series")
    private int series;

    @Column(name = "training_id")
    private int trainingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("exercises")
    private Training training;
```

This would be 2 separate databases referenced by foreign key.

EDIT: This would be 2 separate **tables** (not databases) referenced by foreign key.